# Lasso and FileMaker 13

Tags: filemaker, lasso-lang

Is it possible to get Filemaker server 13 and Lasso 8.6 or 9 to work on the same machine?

I’m trying to get FMS 13 and Lasso 8.6 to run on my development machine, which is OS X 10.9.1.

When I try to load the Lasso_ServerAdmin page I get an error.

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, yes, it is possible to [Configure Lasso 8 and 9 side-by-side on one server](http://www.lassosoft.com/Configure-Lasso-8-and-9-Side-by-Side).

But before you jump right in and install, you should search through [LassoTalk](http://lasso.2283332.n4.nabble.com/Lasso-Talk-f3096191.html) for issues related to 10.9/Mavericks.

You will also need to install Apple's Java 6.

Finally [LassoSoft states](http://www.lassosoft.com/FileMaker): "Dec 17, 2013: We are presently evaluating FileMaker 13 for any changes and impacts."

Although some users have reported limited success with connecting to FM 13 from Lasso, it is not yet ready for production.